# Making one observable after the other one is complete

Tags: angular, rxjs

I subscribe to observable below:

```
    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .startWith({})
        .pairwise()
        .subscribe((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
            if (
                this.breadcrumbs.length > 0 &&
                events[0].url &&
                events[0].url.split("?")[0] === events[1].url.split("?")[0]
            ) {
                return;
            }
            let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
            this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);

            this.checkSetIsHomePage();
            this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
        });
```

and I want to subscribe to observable below when the top one is done:

```
    this.breadcrumbService.additionalBreadcrumbs
        .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        .subscribe(breadcrumb => {
            if (breadcrumb.index) {
                this.breadcrumbs.splice(breadcrumb.index, 0, breadcrumb);
            } else {
                this.breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
            }

            this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
        });
```

these are two separate observable, I used delay but I know its not the best practice to do that, how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: Could you clarify, when do you want to subscribe to the second Observable? Your first Observable never completes but you say in your question/title that you want to subscribe to the second one when the first 'is complete' / 'is done'.

Comment: @fridoo right, it completes when the component destroy is called,but I want always the second observable to emit after  the first observably emits and finished running the code in subscribe, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't subscribe to the first observable, but instead use one more operator to finally subscribe to the second observable.
The operator you want is either mergemap or switchmap.

## EDIT

Could you try this ?

```
this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .startWith({})
    .pairwise()
    .tap((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
        if (
            this.breadcrumbs.length > 0 &&
            events[0].url &&
            events[0].url.split("?")[0] === events[1].url.split("?")[0]
        ) {
            return;
        }
        let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
        this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);

        this.checkSetIsHomePage();
        this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
    })
    .switchMap(() => this.breadcrumbService.additionalBreadcrumbs)
    .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    .subscribe(breadcrumb => {
        if (breadcrumb.index) {
            this.breadcrumbs.splice(breadcrumb.index, 0, breadcrumb);
        } else {
            this.breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
        }

        this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
    });
```

What you do here is use the tap operator to manipulate your "this" on each emit, but you don't change the observable and you don't emit one yourself. Then you switch to the second observable, on each emit of the first.

Comment: This seems to be the solution the OP is looking for. You should improve your answer by adding example code.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the operator that you need at RXJS is [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat)

Instead of subscribing directly to both Observables, you may need to pipe them with a map to perform the operation needed and finally concat them.

```
const observable1 = this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .startWith({})
        .pairwise()
        .pipe(map((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
            if (
                this.breadcrumbs.length > 0 &&
                events[0].url &&
                events[0].url.split("?")[0] === events[1].url.split("?")[0]
            ) {
                return;
            }
            let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
            this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);

            this.checkSetIsHomePage();
            this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
        }));

const observable2 =     this.breadcrumbService.additionalBreadcrumbs
        .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        .pipe(map(breadcrumb => {
            if (breadcrumb.index) {
                this.breadcrumbs.splice(breadcrumb.index, 0, breadcrumb);
            } else {
                this.breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
            }

            this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
        });

concat(observable1,observable2).subscribe()
```

I haven't test it but I think it should work

Comment: I tried this approach but it doesn't call the 'observable2' for some reason.

Comment: because 'observable1' should complete in order run  'observable2'  , any alternative?

Comment: it's weird because I have tested this and works. Please tell me if this also works for you.   ```   const observable1: Observable<void> = of(console.log('Calling observable 1 function'));
    const observable2: Observable<void> = of(console.log('Calling observable 2 function'));
    
    concat(observable1, observable2).subscribe(() => console.log('First aproach'));


    observable1.pipe(switchMap( () => {return observable2} ))
    .subscribe( () => console.log('Second aproach'));```

Answer (score 0):

you can use finalize

```
this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .startWith({})
    .pairwise()
    .pipe(
        finalize(() => {

            this.breadcrumbService.additionalBreadcrumbs
                .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
                .subscribe(breadcrumb => {
                    if (breadcrumb.index) {
                        this.breadcrumbs.splice(breadcrumb.index, 0, breadcrumb);
                    } else {
                        this.breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
                    }

                    this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
                });
        })
    )
    .subscribe((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
        if (
            this.breadcrumbs.length > 0 &&
            events[0].url &&
            events[0].url.split("?")[0] === events[1].url.split("?")[0]
        ) {
            return;
        }
        let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
        this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);

        this.checkSetIsHomePage();
        this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
    });
```

Comment: the first observable should complete in order run the finalize, so it doesnt run the second one, any alternative?