# subscribe to another observable after 'router.events' callback code runs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have subscribed to `router.events` and it doesn't complete since I want to to listen all the time and emit on every url change:

```
    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .startWith({})
        .pairwise()
        .subscribe((events: [NavigationEnd, NavigationEnd]) => {
            if (
                this.breadcrumbs.length > 0 &&
                events[0].url &&
                events[0].url.split("?")[0] === events[1].url.split("?")[0]
            ) {
                return;
            }

            //set breadcrumbs
            let root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
            this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);

            this.checkSetIsHomePage();
            this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
        });
```

but I want my other custom observable to emit after the code above is executed every time, my other observable subscribe is below:

```
    this.breadcrumbService.additionalBreadcrumbs
        .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        .subscribe(breadcrumb => {
            if (breadcrumb.index) {
                this.breadcrumbs.splice(breadcrumb.index, 0, breadcrumb);
            } else {
                this.breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
            }
            this.setBreadcrumbHeight();
        });
```

is there a way to do this without unsubscribing from `router.events` ?

Comment: This is basically the same question as your other one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60344904/9423231 You should edit the first one instead of opening a second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is concatMap
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap